# Why does this css selector work even though it has a bracket missing?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$("span[id^='id_name_'");
```

I found in my code that this selector actually works. I thought it would break because of the mismatching brackets, but it doesn't. Is it because CSS is quite forgiving or is because of the ^ bit of the selector?

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to hard reload your browser